# execute "su" failed in my fully rooted Android device

Tags: android, android-ndk, su

while i add this line to my code

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c");
```

or

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

trying to run the"su" command,

process.exitValue() returns 1 which means fail.

This happens to my one Android device while my the other rooted android device works perfectly with this command. (process.exitValue() returns 0)

Can anyone teach me how to trace the error or how to fix it?

I am confused with this error while my two devices almost in the same condition.

Thanks for your reply in advance.

---

Hi guys,

Thanks for discussing this issue with me. Your reply hints me a clue that I have removed my old su and place a new su. Luckily enough, the return value is now 0 and I guess it means correct. However, Does any of you might know what is the difference between .exec("su -c") and .exec("su")? Please let me know if you know the difference.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys. Let me add a comment that why I am sure that my phone is rooted. when I type adb shell, the # sign pops up.

Comment: Install an app called [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qb2V5a3JpbS5yb290Y2hlY2siXQ..) on your device and see what does it say...

Comment: Check su's manpage http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su. `su -c` is made to issue commands has arguments and should not be used alone. For example `su -c ifconfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **suspect** you lack **Superuser** on the problematic phone, do you?
Or at least something about Superuser could be wrong (versions, binaries...)

`su` calls Superuser which allows root access or not.

Many problems seems to occurs on latest versions of Superuser.

Try to **remove** it and **install** other version:

http://goo.im/superuser

Another note: if you're trying to gain root access or to execute commands as root, you should not only use `exec("su")`. Take a look at the **RootTools** a library by stericson himself ;)

http://code.google.com/p/roottools/

Comment: Can you let me know which directory i should enter to remove the old one and add a new one?

Comment: Safest way it to search for a "System app remover" on the Market. Or use adb shell. su should be `/system/xbin/su` or `/system/xbin/su` and application should be '/system/app/Superuser.apk`. Remove any Superuser updates via the Settings/Applications interface.

Comment: Hi Shkschneider, I did not find the Superuser.apk in my /system/app/ directory but I then adb push one to this directory and reboot my device. Plus, yes, I found my su executable in the /system/xbin/su directory. but what do u mean by "Remove any Superuser updates"??? what's the next step i should trace?

Comment: I think you had issues because Superuser is broken or missing. Just install the latest one from Market should fix your issue.

Comment: Well, I have installed the SuperSU which you can find it in the market. The one works like superuser. I can run this app on my rooted device but still get exitValue 1. This really confuses me. Should I suppose to remove the su executable and place the new one?
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImV1LmNoYWluZmlyZS5zdXBlcnN1Il0.

Comment: Superuser app lets you update the binary from its settings. But if you did what you say you did: I agree, it is a weird issue and I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas, even if I'm still convinced this has something to do which *acquiring root access* and/or *superuser*. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su

Answer (score 1):

The command `su` (which means **Super User**) is only valid on *rooted* phones. That is why your rooted phone recognizes it and works as expected. So, either you root your other device(s) or drop this idea on non-rooted phones :)

Comment: Thanks Waqas. Device is rooted.

Comment: Install an app called [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qb2V5a3JpbS5yb290Y2hlY2siXQ..) on your device and see what does it say...

Comment: well, i can not download it in my location due to Google's restriction. Can you submit a binary for me?

Comment: Waqas, sadly I cant find that's "OK" button to run the Root Checker for some reasons. Is there another way to check it?

Comment: i think your device is not rooted. try installing any app which requires root permission on the phone and then see if it works or not. have you installed **Superuser**?

Comment: If Superuser can be executed only on the rooted phone, then yes, my phone is rooted.

Comment: I just installed it and executed it on my device.

Comment: Do you know other apks need root permission to execute?

Comment: just try installing any app from Google Play which requires root permission. for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree

Comment: I have installed SuperSU and it works perfectly on my rooted device. This means my device is fully rooted. Any other clue? At least, we can be sure that the device has no problem for root matter.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImV1LmNoYWluZmlyZS5zdXBlcnN1Il0.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the only result I got for searching for the phrase, thought I'd post an update for anyone else coming across this.

Was following the instructions for installing [Cyanogenmod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_spyder). My issue was resolved by disabling Mass Storage mode on the device (change it to one of the other options).